How do I use something like next() in Python, but it allows me to "step" over iterations like in a for loop?
I have python code that lets me iterate through a list of combinations and I want to skip over the iterations and generate for example every 100th iteration. I have a next() function that makes the combinations iterate up by one for now but I need to skip over them.
The code that I have right now is:
def fastFunction(string, string1):

    try:
        return next(string)
    except StopIteration:
        return None

This is the function that lets me generate the next iteration in my iterator when it is called.
class MyIterator:

    def __init__(self, hex_string, repeat, mapping_function=None, fixed_string=""):
        self.fixed_string = fixed_string  # Add a parameter for the fixed string
        combined_string = fixed_string+hex_string 
        self.repeat = repeat
        self.mapping_function = mapping_function
        if self.mapping_function:
            combined_string = self.mapping_function(combined_string)
        self.hex_string = combined_string
        self.fixed_part_length = len(fixed_string)
        self.combinations = itertools.product(self.hex_string, repeat=repeat - self.fixed_part_length)
        self.current = fastFunction(self.combinations, None)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def modify_speed(self):
        pass

    def __next__(self):
        if self.current is not None:
            private_key =   self.fixed_string+ ''.join(self.current)    # Ensure the fixed string is part of the final key
            self.current = fastFunction(self.combinations, None)
            return private_key
        else:
            raise StopIteration


This is the iterator, and the function is passed into self.current and other things to make the next combination appear. I want to skip over iterations so i can generate every 100th iteration, for example, instantly. How can I do this?

Could you make def __next__(self): def __next__(self, step=1): and use that step variable to maybe execute step times fastFunction (Or whatever it should do, it's not clear to me) before returning?

An iterator is an iterator. It iterates over a predetermined sequence (even if the items of that sequence are actually generated on the fly). You have the option to create the generator with different arguments, so the sequence it will iterate over will be different (e.g. range(1, 100, step=20)). Or you can simply not use certain elements of the generated sequence (e.g. islice).

I don't get it guys can you be more clear? I just want to be able to skip over iterations @deceze

next doesn't allow you to skip iterations; next just takes the next value. Again, do you understand the range(..., step=20) example? Instead of range going += 1 with every step, it'll go += 20 with every step and thus "skip" values. If you can set up your generator like that, that's the best solution. Otherwise, if you want to skip 19 values of a generator, you have to call next 20 times and simply discard the first 19 values you got. And islice basically does that for you. Clearer?

I don't understand. You built a tool that lets you skip an iteration, and you seem to have it tested and working properly. And now the question is how to skip multiple iterations? Did you try... using the tool that lets you skip an iteration, multiple times in a row?

There is itertools.islice that allow you to step through an iterator and possibly skipping elements. But if the iterator you're iterating through is produced by itertools.product, itertools.combinations, itertools.combinations_with_replacement or itertools.permutations and you're skipping many of them, it might be more efficient to write your own generator function that generates directly the combinations you're interested in and doesn't waste time "generating then skipping" the others.

in your code next iteration depends on value from previous iteration - so you have to run all of them. You may only skip results - so you can generate all values and later get all_values[::100]. OR your code has to run loop which generates 100 results and send back only last result - 100th.

in __next__ you could use loop for _ in range(100): self.current = fastFunction(self.combinations, None) in place of line self.current = fastFunction(self.combinations, None). OR you would have to use this for _ in range(100): ... inside fastFunction()
